# Show that the set $X_s = \{A\in M_{m\times n}(\Bbb {R}) | rk(A) \leq s\}$ is closed

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

**A bit of background:**

I am trying to show that if $f\in C^1(\Bbb {R}^n,\Bbb{R}^m)$ then for every $a\in \Bbb{R}^n$ there exists a neighborrhood $U$ of $a$ s.t. for every $x\in U$ we have $rk(Df(x))\geq rk(Df(a))$.

I am trying to prove this by contradition,  suppose there isn't such a neighborrhood of $a$ with this property, then there is a sequence $x_k\to a$ s.t. $rk(Df(x_k))<rk(Df(a))$ for every $k$. Since the degree only takes on finitely any values there is a sub-sequence $x_{k_l}\to a$ with $rk(Df(x_{k_l})) = s<rk(Df(a))$ Hence if $X_s = \{A\in M_{m\times n}(\Bbb {R}) | rk(A) \leq s\}$ is closed then we get a contradiction since then $Df(a)\in X_s$ which we assumed isent true.

**Here are a few of my attempts**:

- I will denote $V = M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)$ throughout this post.

$\mathbf {Attempt}$ $\mathbf{one:}$

Induction on $s$, for $s=0$ the statment is obvious since $X_0 = \{0\}$ which is closed.
now lets assume the statment is true for $s$, every matrix in $X_{s+1}$ can be written as $A+B$ where $A\in X_s$ and $B\in X_1$ so:

$$X_{s+1}\subseteq X_{s}+X_1$$

This is a sum of two closed sets in $V$ so we only need to show it is closed (which is not always true - there are closed subsets whose sum isn't).
Now if $A\in \partial ( X_{s}+X_1)$ then there is a sequence $B_k+C_k\to A$ s.t. $B_k\in  X_s$ and $C_k\in X_1$ $\mathbf {IF}$  $B_k\to B$ and $C_k\to C$ converege themselves then the statment is obvius since:

$$A = lim_{k\to \infty} B_k+C_k = lim_{k\to \infty} B_k +lim_{k\to \infty} C_k =B+C\in X_s+X_1$$
since $B\in X_s$ and $C \in  X_1$ since they are closed by the induction hypothesis and so $A\in  X_s+X_1$ and we are done. However, it might be that $B_k$ and $C_k$ dont converge so we have a problem.

In this case, my qeustions are:

- can we choose a two convergeing sequences $B_k,C_k$ s.t. $B_k\in X_s$ and $C_k \in X_1$  and $B_k+C_k\to A$
- If not, can we show the sum is closed by some other method?

$\mathbf{Attempt}$ $\mathbf{two:}$

Notice that Gaussian elimination is a linear (hence continuous) and preserves rank so if $A_k\to A$ where $A_k \in  X_s$ then by applying Gaussian elimination to $A$ we can bring it to the form $\varphi(A)=diag(a_1,...,a_u,0,...,0)$ and since $\varphi$ is continuous we have $\varphi(A_k)\to diag(a_1,...,a_u,0,...,0)$ hence $[\varphi(A_k)]_{ij}\to \delta_{i,j,\leq u} a_i$ where $\delta_{i,j,\leq u} = 1$ iff $i=j\leq u$.

Let us write:
$$\varphi(A_k) = \begin{pmatrix}
(v_1)_k \\
\vdots \\
(v_s)_k \\
\sum_{i=0}^{s} x^k_{s+1,i} (v_i)_k \\
\vdots \\
\sum_{i=0}^{s} x^k_{m,i} (v_i)_k\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

So $(v_i)_k\to a_i\cdot e_i$ for each $1\leq i\leq s$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{s} x^k_{j,i} (v_i)_k \to 0 $ for each $s+1\leq j\leq m$.

Here I am pretty much stuck.

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be any matrix in $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$. If $A=0$, clearly every matrix in $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$ has equal or larger rank. Suppose $A\ne0$, so that the rank of $A$ is some $r>0$. Then $A$ has an invertible $r\times r$ submatrix. Since the determinant function is continuous in the matrix entries, for every matrix $B$ that is sufficiently close to $A$, the corresponding submatrix in $B$ is also invertible. Hence $\operatorname{rank}(B)\ge r$.

Now the result follows from the above fact and the fact that $Df$ is continuous.